# Jackson deserialize dynamically by class fully Qualified Name

Tags: java, json

I am working on the framework which has these requirements

Developers develop their classes ( Beans ) like below

```
class BeanA{
  
    int id;
    String appName;

   public void save() 
}

class BeanB{
  
    int id;
    String userName;

   public void save() 
}
```

There is `orchestratoon.csv` is also defined like this where developer makes the entry of their class

```
org.example.BeanA, http://fetch/bean/a/from/this/url
org.example.BeanB, http://fetch/bean/b/from/this/url
org.example.BeanC, http://fetch/bean/c/from/this/url
```

After this, I have to write a platform service, which will fetch the Beans data from the `url` given in the `orchestration.csv` file and render then in the class provided by their `fully qualified name`

My problem is, how can I deserialize the json fetched into the class given by its name and call a `save` method of that bean.

Below is the psuedo code.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

for className, URL in CSV
  
   String json = getObject(url)

   // Here is the problem, how do I deserialize it using ObjectMapper 
   
     objectMapper.readValue(json, Class.forName(className));   ---> It does not work , compile time error because of Class.forName and how do I call a save on it
```

Any help would

Comment: Please edit question to add exact compile error message. `objectMapper.readValue(json, Class.forName(className));` works, but you will have to cast the result from `Object` to something more concrete.

Comment: You probably want all of the classes to implement an interface that defines the `save` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the `save()` method in an interface or abstract class, depending on your exact scenario. In most cases interface is better choice:

```
public interface MyInterface {

  void save();
}
```

Have `BeanA`, `BeanB`, etc. implement it. Cast the deserialization result to `MyInterface` and invoke `save()`.

```
Object object;
try {
  object = objectMapper.readValue(json, Class.forName("bean.class.full.name"));
} catch (JsonProcessingException exc) {
  throw new RuntimeException("invalid json", exc);
}
if (object instanceof MyInterface myInterface) {
  myInterface.save();
} else {
  throw new RuntimeException("appropriate message here");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you managed to read the JSON string that represents particular class from your URL and you know the class name. So you can use `ObjectMapper` class and its method `<T> T readValue(String content, Class<T> valueType)`. Place your json string as a content and as for class use 
`public static Class<?> forName(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException`. See ObjectMapper javadoc [here](https://javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.14.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html).
Also, if you want it even simpler I wrote my own JsonUtil where you don't even have to instantiate ObjectMapper. Your code would look like this:

```
 try {
    BeanB beanB = JsonUtils.readObjectFromJsonString(jsonStr, Class.forName(classNameStr));
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ...
}
```

In this example class `JsonUtils` comes with Open Source MgntUtils library written and maintained by me. See [the Javadoc for JsonUtils class](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html). The MgntUtils library can be obtained from [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) as Maven artifact or from [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) along with Source code and Javadoc

Comment: So far good but how do you hold the object returned by ObjectMapper ? As of now, you have defined it in `BeanB beanB` which is hardcoded , it can be BeanA beanA ..

Comment: @voila One idea is that all those beans should implement the same interface (say MyBean). Than you can always receive it as MyBean and it could be BeanA or BeanB or any other implementation